# Read values through TwinCAT ADS without PLC variable declaration

Tags: c#, twincat, twincat-ads

I'm new to EtherCAT/TwinCAT. I have a slave device connected to Master. I can read data with an ADS Client  from the slave device if I create a variable in my PLC and link that variable to a value on the slave. Is there a way to get a value from the slave without having to create a PLC variable? I'd like to be able to read and modify multiple objects on the slave without having to create a variable for each in the PLC.

Comment: In principle ADS is not restricted to read/write plc variables. With ADS, functions/data are identified with AMSNetId,AMSPort,Group and Offset and this allows for much more than just read/write plc variables. For instance, in addition to read/write plc variables I retrieve information about plc variables, set/get all kinds of states, retrieve version info and do all sorts of stuff with axes. However I don't think ADS allows for what you want, please have a look at; https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tc3_ads_intro/index.html

Can you tell more about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hardware that will be controlled through the TwinCAT master will be developed in isolated sub-systems and then integrated together. Most of the control of these sub-systems and the system as a whole will be done through a separate program, not through PLC logic. So, for the most part, we are using the EtherCAT fieldbus as a means to control hardware from our program. The hardware configuration of the sub-systems will likely change / be shared between sub-systems in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to enable this functionality all you need to do is Enable ADS Server on the EtherCAT device that you are trying to access.

#### Making ADS IO symbols available

There are a few setup steps that are required to make this work, but it is reasonably straight-forward.

1. Scan in IO from EtherCAT chain
2. Add a new 'Twincat Task with Image'

   - Added from the context menu of 'System>Tasks'
3. Create and link variable from added task to IO

   - Force the sync-unit updates and allow control of EtherCAT timing
   - *I added a variable that linked to the SlaveCount with a UINT, very basic*
4. For EtherCAT master enable 'Enable ADS Server' and 'Create Symbols'
5. Access Symbols as you would any other on the controller

   - *Only oddity around this is that you need to access the CONTROLLER net ID, not the EtherCAT master, But you still use the port from the EtherCAT master*

---

**Where to find 'Enable ADS Server', 'Create Symbols' and ADS Port**

[image: Enabling the ADS Server]

---

**Example Symbol path in the IO device list**

[image: Symbol path as shown in XAE]

Comment: I've enabled the ADS Server and Create symbols on the device. I can read / write to the devices now, but the only way I was able to do this was use the symbol loader to find the devices and their index groups and index offsets; they don't match the ADS info of the devices shown on their variable tab. The index offset matches the Address of the device but I can't find where the index group comes from.

Comment: @Vic I'm not entirely sure what the issue is with your accessing. I have been able to access the symbol data with no major concerns. Create Tasks with Image -> Link to a generic IO -> Activate system -> ADS connection to controller and port. I've updated my answer to try and make the flow clearer but will need review.

Comment: I setup my project as you described and it works! I can read and write info using the ADS info or the Symbol info. The strange thing is I went back to my old project and then was able to read and write without changing anything. Can't figure out what happened, but it's working now. Thanks! I accepted your answer, but am unable to give you an upvote.